# Multiple SQL Select Queries with Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, select, multiple-select

searched a lot but couldn't find a solution to my problem.
First I have a script from which i make a few querys through a local Veeam database.
It has a few select querys but everytime I run it, it just gives me the results of the first one but not from the others. I just tried to make the code a little more skinny so maybe somebody could give me a tip
I just get the results for $job and $space_backup. I don't want to have four different querys but if it's not possible I have to go with it. I would appreciate any help.

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$dbServer;Database=$db;uid=$User;password=$Pass;"
$SQLConnection.Open()
$SQLCommand = $SQLConnection.CreateCommand()
$SQLCommand.CommandText = 
"SELECT TOP 1 stored_size AS size, job_name AS job FROM [VeeamBackup].[dbo].[ReportSessionView] ORDER BY [creation_time] DESC;"
"SELECT [free_space] AS [free] FROM [VeeamBackup].[dbo].[BackupRepositories] WHERE (name != 'Default Backup Repository');"
"SELECT  SUM(backup_size) AS backupsize FROM [VeeamBackup].[dbo].[WmiServer.RestorePointsView];"
"SELECT TOP 1 reason AS Reason, stop_details AS Detail FROM [VeeamBackup].[dbo].[Backup.Model.JobSessions] ORDER BY creation_time DESC;"
$SQLReader = $SQLCommand.ExecuteReader()
foreach($SQLCommand in $SQLReader.Read()){
    $space_backup = $SQLReader["size"]
    $job = $SQLReader["job"]
    $space_free = $SQLReader["free"]
    $space_all = $SQLReader["backupsize"]
    $reason = $SQLReader["Reason"]
    $detail = $SQLReader["Detail"]
    $SQLReader.Close()
}
```

Comment: Run each query separately.

Comment: any other ideas instead of this unhelpful comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you. Just add the SqlDataAdapter and DataSet in place of your $SQLReader = $SQLCommand.ExecuteReader() command and make the selects one long string.  I ended each of mine while testing this with a **;** .

```
$readAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$readSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$readAdapter.SelectCommand = $SQLCommand
$readAdapter.Fill($readSet) |out-null
$SQLConnection.Close()
Foreach ($row in $readSet.Tables[0].rows) {
   Write-Output "Do what you want with the first query results here"
   Write-Output "$($row.size)  $($row.job)"
}
Foreach ($row in $readSet.Tables[1].rows) {
   Write-Output "Do what you want with the second query results here"
   Write-Output "$($row.free)  "
}
```

Keep adding a Foreach for each query

Comment: Doesn't work as I imagined, when I try it in PS i get a new table with the input from "free" but it won't give me anything in the variable $free, same with other foreach. It won't fill the table.

Comment: Got the mistake had to put the $row variable to $row2 and so on
`Foreach ($row in $readSet.Tables[0].rows) {$space_backup = $row[0]; $job = $row[1]}
Foreach ($row2 in $readSet.Tables[1].rows) {$space_free = $row2[0]}
Foreach ($row3 in $readSet.Tables[2].rows) {$space_all = $row3[0]}
Foreach ($row4 in $readSet.Tables[3].rows) {$reason = $row4[0]; $detail = $row4[1] }`

works like a charm thank you!

Comment: You're correct.  I just edited my answer to add the $row.size.  Apologies for the mistake.